# Как обособляются вводные слова в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

*Может, я и ошибся, а может, и нет ― не знаю, не мне судить. **Это во-первых. А во-вторых вот что***. [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)]

Нужна ли здесь запятая: *А во-вторых **вот что***.

В Нацкорпусе по-разному пишут: ***Это во-первых. Это, во-первых***.

А как правильно? И какое здесь можно применить правило?

Спасибо.

Comment: Мне кажется, "вот что" по каким-то причинам нивелирует вводность (не во всех причём случаях). *"Мне кажется, ты неправ. И ещё мне кажется вот что: ..."*; *"Понимаете ли, в чём дело? И понимаете ли вот что: ..."* Ощущение, что, нивелируя вводность, это сочетание как бы лишает вводное слово абстракции, придаёт буквализм: например, понимаете ли вы, в буквальном смысле, то-то и то-то. *"А впрочем, вы были правы, и так же впрочем вот что: ..."* Но я ума не приложу, какими правилами тут руководствоваться.

Comment: Нивелирует, да.  При этом вводное слово превращается в наречие? В Справочнике по пунктуации такой случай не отмечен, а у Розенталя?   Ну а если оно все-таки вводное, то могут указательные слова (это, во что) относиться непосредственно к вводным словам (как, к примеру, союз А)? По интонации  там запятые не нужны.

Comment: У Розенталя я даже похожего не припомню. Ну, не всегда в наречие, в случае с "понимаете" -- в обычный глагол. А вводные-прилагательные, кажется, вообще не подвержены этой нивелирующей силе: *"Похоже, вот что: ..."*, *"Пожалуй, вот что: ..."*

Comment: Я посмотрел Нацкорпус, и мне показалось, что "Это во-первых" встречается чаще. Мне тоже думается, что здесь "во-первых" является уже не вводным, а наречным выражением типа "в первую очередь", да и грамматика не позволяет поставить запятую (для нее нужно продолжение). А вот дальше запятую я бы поставил: "Во-вторых, вот что".

Comment: Кстати, "А во-вторых вот что" может быть инверсией: "А вот что во-вторых: ...".

Comment: @Nektoid Александр Стрелец  Полагаю, что запятые не нужны в обоих случаях. Форманты ЭТО и ВОТ ЧТО имеют указательное значение. Они могут указывать на ранее сказанное (это), а также на то, что будет сказано в дальнейшем (вот что). Слова "во-первых», «во-вторых" используются как самостоятельные и образуют отдельные предложения, поэтому вводными являются только по смыслу, а не грамматике. Ну и, соответственно, не обособляются от указательных частиц, которые к ним относятся.

Comment: Можно записать так: это первое (в первую очередь), а второе (во вторую очередь) вот что. Но самостоятельными могут быть не все вводные слова. Сравним: «Пожалуй, вот что». Здесь значение неполной уверенности «возможно, может быть, вероятно» относится к тому, что будет сказано в дальнейшем. Поэтому это не частица, а вводное слово, которое нужно обособить.

Comment: Я не против отсутствия запятой в обоих предложениях. 